# LinkedIn Integration Into an Android Application

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api

I am building a LinkedIn sharing feature for my Android application. I am able to log into LinkedIn, but afterwards the emulator is showing a blank screen. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code, with my `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` removed:

```java
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClient;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInAccessToken;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthService;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInRequestToken;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Person;
import com.ndot.sample.R;
import com.ndot.sample.TestConnect;


public class LinkedinActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    public static final String APP_NAME = "LITest";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-linkedin";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "litestcalback";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME
            + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
    private static final int BOOK_SELECT = 1;
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares");

    final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory
            .getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(CONSUMER_KEY,
                    CONSUMER_SECRET);
    final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory
            .newInstance(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
    LinkedInApiClient client;
    TextView tv;
    private String oauth_verifier;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.hionCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.post);
        tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postscreen);
        liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken
                .getAuthorizationUrl()));
    Log.d("log",liToken.getAuthorizationUrl());


    }

        @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
        LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier);
        client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
        client.postNetworkUpdate("LinkedIn Android app test");
        Person p = client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
        tv.setText(p.getLastName() + ", " + p.getFirstName());
        LinkedInAccessToken accessToken1 = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, oauth_verifier);
        SharedPreferences prefs = null;
        final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
        edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret());
        edit.putString("linkedin_login", "valid");


    }
    protected void onNewIntent1(Intent intent) {
    String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier"); LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier); 
    client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

    Intent t = new Intent(LinkedinActivity.this, LinkedinConstants.class);
    startActivity(t);
    }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply appropriate amounts of error handling, logging, and debugging.  I don't see any error or failure conditions checked for.   Is your callback called?  Try stepping through the debugger.

While I am bit new to Linkedin development, I'm quite familiar with Android development and also have gotten Linkedin widgets to work over the web.  Before getting the authorization token, you need to get back some verification from Linkedin.  This is where the callback comes into play.

I hope this gets you in the right direction.  Let us know what you find.